# Interpolating a Variable in a C++11 Regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, string-interpolation

Is there a way to interpolate a variable into a regex in C++11?

For example I want this regex: `^((?:\w+ ){$index})\w+`
But I have to write all this code to get there:

```
vector< char > stringIndex( numeric_limits< int >::digits10 + 2 );
_itoa_s( index, stringIndex.begin()._Ptr, stringIndex.size(), 10 );
const string stringRegex( "^((?:\\w+ ){" );
regex goal( stringRegex + stringIndex.begin()._Ptr + "})\\w+" );
```

Surely there is a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the integer to string.

```
regex goal( "^((?:\\w+ ){" + std::to_string(index) + "})\\w+" );
```

By the way, the `_Ptr` member of `vector<T>::iterator` you keep accessing all over is implementation specific and makes your code unportable. You should use the `vector::data` member function instead.

Also, you can avoid all the additional backslashes by using [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

```
regex goal( R"reg(^((?:\w+ ){)reg" + std::to_string(index) + R"reg(})\w+)reg" );
```

Comment: Yeah... I think _itoa_s isn't portable either right? But the wonderful to_string solution would take away the need for that anyway.

Comment: @JonathanMee It isn't, and neither is `itoa`. Prior to `to_string` the portable methods would be using `stringstream` or `sprintf`.